# How to fix shading problems with this object?

Tags: shaders

I have these models of two labeled plastic buckets: one of the labels has some kind of shading problem with dark line in the middle. I tried to fix it but nothing seems to be working. I got more meshes with the same problem. Is there a fix? Please help

https://pasteall.org/blend/930f1c0ba57046fbbb3532c8787f6081

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scale is absolutely tiny for that object! Apply the scale and it will have perfect shading.

[image]